# How to run angular dart 2 route directly from url?

Tags: angular, dart

I'm trying [this example](https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-5) and i understand their demo link still working, but i doesn't work on my local.

I entered "/", it's working.
but i enter "/dashboard" to browser directly, it's not working.

is there anyone know how to fix this problem? i think maybe it relate to configuration in somewhere?

Comment: There no way to detect problem of your end, the way you represent problem you are facing. Provide some snippet or code to find out problem.

Comment: i posted link to code in my question Christian! I'm using sourcecode from dart site https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-5

Comment: `pub serve` doesn't know, that it needs to redirect the request to `index.html`. And even nginx or apache need to be configured to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Run pub:Build on pubspec.yaml, 
after successful build, open 'build' folder and run index.html. In url go to route: index.html#/dashboard

Comment: actually i don't want a hash, if using hash it's working fine.